# React - is there a similar way of declaring state properties?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, flux

So, in the new ES6 React way, seeing such a thing is very common:

```
render()

  const { thing1, thing2, thing3 } = this.props

  ...other stuff
```

Is there a comparable method for state properties, which may or may not exist?

It gets very tiresome to have to use state variables like this:

```
<h1>{this.state && this.state.title ? this.state.title : ''}</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually called destructuring assignment, it's an es6 feature you can read about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

You can easily just do, to any object:

```
const { title } = this.state
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. Rarely does one get literally the answer they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `this.state` is always non-null if you give it a value during construction.  And you can usually simplify the title test with a simple `||`: `this.state.title || ""`.

Here's a full example:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        thing1: PropTypes.string,
        thing2: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    // initialize state during construction
    state = { title: undefined, a: 1, b: 2 };

    render() {
        const { thing1, thing2 } = this.props;
        const { title, a, b } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                 {thing1 && <div>{thing1}</div>}
                 <div>{thing2}</div> {/* isRequired so will never be null */}
                 <div>{title || ""}</div>
                 {a && <div>{a}</div>} {/* only render if a is truthy */}
                 <div>{b || "no b"}</div> {/* render "no b" if b not set */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```